# How to load navbar dropdown list content in bootstrap 4?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have created a navbar with dropdown menu. When i click navbar tab that would load the content what I

```html
    <div class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#one">One</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#two">Two</a>
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbardrop"
          data-toggle="dropdown" href="#three">Three</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-center">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href='#threeA'>Three_A</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href='#threeB'>Three_B</a>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="one">1</div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="two">2</div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="three/threeA">3a</div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="three/threeB">3b</div>
    </div>
```

I have mentioned in href and loaded in id. But if I click dropdown list it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Bootstrap 4 requires jQuery to work. Instead of default Bootstrap 4 you can use [NgBootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home). They have an [NgbDropdown component](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples) that I was able to implement easily in my navbar

```
<div ngbDropdown>
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" ngbDropdownToggle">Open Dropdown</a>
    <div ngbDropdownMenu>
        <a routerLink="link/to/page1">Link 1</a>
        <a routerLink="link/to/page2">Link 2</a>
        <a routerLink="link/to/page3">Link 3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No. My code also work, If I am using routerLink to rent my content. But I am trying to rent my content by using href and id.

Comment: I don't see any code that will change which tab has the active class based on the route you select, unless that's a feature of the bootstrap dropdown I'm not aware of.